# Windows XP: resetting sharing permissions for a file to those of the directory it is contained in

Tags: windows-xp, security, file-sharing

Followup question for [my previous one](https://superuser.com/questions/370408/windows-xp-local-network-sharing-1gb-zip-file-is-blocked-seeing-access-denie):

So I have a directory `\etc\install\foo` that allows file sharing.

I have a file `NEW.zip` from an unshared location that I moved into `\etc\install\foo`, and therefore `NEW.zip` does not inherit permissions from `\etc\install\foo`.

Is there an easy way to reset the permissions for `NEW.zip` so that it *does* inherit permissions from its containing directory `\etc\install\foo` ?

(without manually trying to match permissions, which is a pain, and without copying the file, which is problematic for very large files, hence the whole reason it was moved and not copied to its present location)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open the file's *Properties - Security* tab and click on *Advanced*
2. Look for a checkbox **"Inherit from parent the permission entries..."**
3. If "Inherit" is already enabled, disable it and choose *Remove* when prompted.
4. Remove all permission entries from the list.
5. Enable "Inherit" again.
6. Click OK to close both windows.

If the current ACL disallows further ACL modifications, you can override it by taking ownership of the file. (The owner can *always* modify ACLs.) If Windows doesn't prompt you automatically, you can take ownership from *Advanced - Owner*; you must be an administrator to do so.

Comment: sweet! I found the Properties - Security - Advanced tab myself, but had no idea what to do with it. Thanks!